# apex list of object

Tags: apex, custom-object, list

I have a list of objects:

```
List<Volume_Detail__c> listVolumesDetails = new List<Volume_Detail__c>([SELECT Id,Year__c,January_Volume__c, April_Volume__c,Volume__c  FROM Volume_Detail__c WHERE Volume__r.Id IN :volumeIds ]);
```

listVolumesDetails variable debug log:

> (Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRtNUAW, Year__c=2023.00,
> January_Volume__c=0.00, April_Volume__c=0.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZyvxUAD},
>
> Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRtSUAW, Year__c=2021.00,
> January_Volume__c=0.00, April_Volume__c=0.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZyvxUAD},
>
> Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRtTUAW, Year__c=2022.00,
> January_Volume__c=200.00, April_Volume__c=200.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZyvxUAD},
>
> Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRu6UAG, Year__c=2023.00,
> January_Volume__c=0.00, April_Volume__c=0.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZz8IUAT},
>
> Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRu7UAG, Year__c=2024.00,
> January_Volume__c=100.00, April_Volume__c=0.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZz8IUAT},
>
> Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRu8UAG, Year__c=2025.00,
> January_Volume__c=100.00, April_Volume__c=0.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZz8IUAT},
>
> Volume_Detail__c:{Id=a0K7Z000007IRu9UAG, Year__c=2026.00,
> January_Volume__c=0.00, April_Volume__c=20.00,
> Volume__c=a0J7Z00000UZz8IUAT}

I want to calculate for example for the year 2023, the total of **January_Volume__c** and the total of **April_Volume__c**, How can I proceed with that as a best practice in apex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map to store the sum of the `January_Volume__c` and `April_Volume__c` fields for each year.
You can use the `Year__c` field as the key and the sum as the value.
You can then access the map by the desired year to get the sum.
For example, you can use this code:

```
Map<Decimal, Decimal> mapOfYearAndJanVolume = new Map<Decimal, Decimal>();
Map<Decimal, Decimal> mapOfYearAndAprVolume = new Map<Decimal, Decimal>();
for (Volume_Detail__c vd : listVolumesDetails) {
        Decimal year = vd.Year__c;
        if (mapOfYearAndJanVolume.containsKey(year)) {
                Decimal currentTotal = mapOfYearAndJanVolume.get(year);
                Decimal newTotal = currentTotal + vd.January_Volume__c;
                mapOfYearAndJanVolume.put(year, newTotal);
        } else {
                mapOfYearAndJanVolume.put(year, vd.January_Volume__c);
        }

        if (mapOfYearAndAprVolume.containsKey(year)) {
                Decimal currentTotal = mapOfYearAndAprVolume.get(year);
                Decimal newTotal = currentTotal + vd.April_Volume__c;
                mapOfYearAndAprVolume.put(year, newTotal);
        } else {
                mapOfYearAndAprVolume.put(year, vd.April_Volume__c);
        }
}

System.debug('The total of January 2023 :: ' + mapOfYearAndJanVolume.get(2023));
System.debug('The total of April 2023 :: ' + mapOfYearAndAprVolume.get(2023));
```

You can also use the **AggregateQuery**. To use the **AggregateResult** object and the **GROUP BY** and **SUM** clauses. The **AggregateResult** object stores the results of an aggregate query, such as the sum of a field or the count of records. The **GROUP BY** clause groups the records by one or more fields, such as the `Year__c` field. The **SUM** clause calculates the sum of a numeric field, such as the `January_Volume__c` and `April_Volume__c` fields. For example, you can use this code:

```
List<AggregateResult> listAggregateResults = [SELECT Year__c, SUM(January_Volume__c) AS January_Total, SUM(April_Volume__c) AS April_Total FROM Volume_Detail__c WHERE Volume__r.Id IN :volumeIds GROUP BY Year__c];
for (AggregateResult ar : listAggregateResults) {
        System.debug('The total for the year ' + ar.get('Year__c') + ' is ' + (ar.get('January_Total') + ' and ' + ar.get('April_Total')));
}
```

======================================

You can do this for all months:

#1:

```
Map<Decimal, Map<String, Decimal>> mapOfYearAndMonthVolume = new Map<Decimal, Map<String, Decimal>>();
List<String> months = new List<String>new List<String>{'January_Volume__c', 'February_Volume__c', 'March_Volume__c', 'April_Volume__c','May_Volume__c','June_Volume__c','July_Volume__c','August_Volume__c', 'September_Volume__c','October_Volume__c','November_Volume__c','December_Volume__c' };

for (Volume_Detail__c vd : listVolumesDetails) {
        Decimal year = vd.Year__c;
        if (!mapOfYearAndMonthVolume.containsKey(year)) {
                mapOfYearAndMonthVolume.put(year, new Map<String, Decimal>());
        }
        Map<String, Decimal> mapOfMonthAndVolume = mapOfYearAndMonthVolume.get(year);
        for (String month : months) {
                Decimal volume = (Decimal)vd.get(month);
                if (mapOfMonthAndVolume.containsKey(month)) {
                        Decimal currentTotal = mapOfMonthAndVolume.get(month);
                        Decimal newTotal = currentTotal + volume;
                        mapOfMonthAndVolume.put(month, newTotal);
                } else {
                        mapOfMonthAndVolume.put(month, volume);
                }
        }
}

System.debug('The total of January 2023 :: ' + mapOfYearAndMonthVolume.get(2023).get('January_Volume__c'));
System.debug('The total of April 2023 :: ' + mapOfYearAndMonthVolume.get(2023).get('April_Volume__c'));
```

#2

```
List<AggregateResult> listAggregateResults = [SELECT Year__c, SUM(January_Volume__c) AS January_Total, SUM(February_Volume__c) AS February_Total, SUM(March_Volume__c) AS March_Total,SUM(April_Volume__c) AS April_Total,SUM(May_Volume__c) AS May_Total,SUM(June_Volume__c) AS June_Total,SUM(July_Volume__c) AS July_Total,SUM(August_Volume__c) AS August_Total,SUM(September_Volume__c) AS September_Total,SUM(October_Volume__c) AS October_Total,SUM(November_Volume__c) AS November_Total, SUM(December_Volume__c) AS December_Total FROM Volume_Detail__c WHERE Volume__r.Id IN :volumeIds GROUP BY Year__c];
for (AggregateResult ar : listAggregateResults) {
        System.debug('The total for the year ' + ar.get('Year__c') + ' is as below:');
        System.debug(' January = ' + (ar.get('January_Total'));
        System.debug(' February = ' + (ar.get('February_Total'));
        System.debug(' March = ' + (ar.get('March_Total'));
        System.debug(' April = ' + (ar.get('April_Total'));
        System.debug(' May = ' + (ar.get('May_Total'));
        System.debug(' June = ' + (ar.get('June_Total'));
        System.debug(' July = ' + (ar.get('July_Total'));
        System.debug(' August = ' + (ar.get('August_Total'));
        System.debug(' September = ' + (ar.get('September_Total'));
        System.debug(' October = ' + (ar.get('October_Total'));
        System.debug(' November = ' + (ar.get('November_Total'));
        System.debug(' December = ' + (ar.get('December_Total'));
}
```

Comment: The three letter abbreviation for April is is Apr, not Apl. One should always strive to use standard abbreviations, if using abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks for the support , really appreciate it. if i want to make more dynamic is it possible to include a list of static months to do the same work for all the months ? : : List<String> enumMonths = new List<String>{'January_Volume__c', 'February_Volume__c', 'March_Volume__c', 'April_Volume__c','May_Volume__c','June_Volume__c','July_Volume__c','August_Volume__c', 'September_Volume__c','October_Volume__c','November_Volume__c','December_Volume__c' };

Comment: @NBO I have added code for all months in the answer. Please check.

Comment: yeah for the first suggestion i mean 
if we repeate it for 12 month it will be too much i think 
not sure if we can replace the api name of the months dynamically

Comment: @NBO I have added code for all months for #1 also. Please check.